# How to add custom widget to another custom widget in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am pretty new to the kivy language and faced this problem when try to run the following code. it just runs without any errors. But it just only generate a blank application. without any widgets.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

kv = """
<SCManager>:
    Screen:
        c_screen:

<c_screen>:
    cols: 2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    MDBoxLayout:
        md_bg_color: (1, 1, 1 ,1)
        padding: 10
        adaptive_height: True

        MDLabel:
            text: "helow 2"
            color: (0.0003, 0.34, 0.60,1)
            font_style: "H6"
            halign: "left"
            adaptive_height: True

<navigator>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDLabel:
        text: "hellow"
        adaptive_height: True

    MDList:
        OneLineAvatarListItem:
            text : "Dashboard"
            IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                icon: "view-dashboard"


        OneLineAvatarListItem:
            text : "Manage Users"
            IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                icon: "account"

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        text: "bye"
        font_size: 11

"""


class SCManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class navigator(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class c_screen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n = navigator()
        self.add_widget(self.n)


class test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return SCManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

But if i add another widget(a label) to Screen from kv string, it works fine or if i use add_widget(c_screen) in SCManager it works fine.But i need to add c_screen class from the kv string. Is there any way to add widgets without adding any widgets to Screen??

here is the working code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

kv = """
<SCManager>:
    Screen:
        MDLabel:
            text: "helow 2"
            adaptive_height: True
        c_screen:

<c_screen>:
    cols: 2
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    MDBoxLayout:
        md_bg_color: (1, 1, 1 ,1)
        adaptive_height: True

        MDLabel:
            text: "helow 2"
            adaptive_height: True

<navigator>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDLabel:
        text: "hellow"
        adaptive_height: True

    MDList:
        OneLineAvatarListItem:
            text : "Dashboard"
            IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                icon: "view-dashboard"

        OneLineAvatarListItem:
            text : "Manage Users"
            IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch:
                icon: "account"

    MDRoundFlatIconButton:
        text: "bye"
        font_size: 11

"""


class SCManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class navigator(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class c_screen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.n = navigator()
        self.add_widget(self.n)


class test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return SCManager()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

Comment: Name your widget classes starting with an uppercase letter, kv uses this to distinguish them from properties.

Comment: highly appreciate the help inclement. It solved the problem. thank you